# Android Json Parsing from Asp.net Json Webservice Data

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, web-services

I am trying to get data in android app through asp.net Json webservice. Webservice is returning perfect data but I am not able to get data in Android App.

My code is as below, Please help me to solve the problem :
UTL_Categories is url of the webservice and GetCity is the method name.

```
private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    tv.setText("");

    for (int i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(cityList.get(i).getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerFood.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

private class GetCities extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CityData.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Cities..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        String json = sh
                .makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray cities = jsonObj.getJSONArray("GetCity");

                    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) cities.get(i);
                        City cat = new City(catObj.getInt("CityId"),
                                catObj.getString("CityName"));
                        cityList.add(cat);

                        result = (cities.length());
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return String.valueOf(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();

        tv.setText(result);
    }

}
```

result is showing 0 where it has 200 data.

**Stack Trace :**

```
    01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131): > 
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131): <html>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     <head><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="/JsonAndroid.asmx?disco" />
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     <style type="text/css">
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      A:hover { color: cc3300; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      P { color: #000000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 12px; font-family: Verdana; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      pre { background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; font-size: x-small; margin-top: -5px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      td { color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      h2 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #003366; margin-left: -15px; color: #003366; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      h3 { font-size: 1.1em; color: #000000; margin-left: -15px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      ul { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      ol { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      li { margin-top: 10px; color: #000000; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      font.value { color: darkblue; font: bold; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      font.key { color: darkgreen; font: bold; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      font.error { color: darkred; font: bold; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      .heading1 { color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; background-color: #003366; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: -30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 15px; width: 105%; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      .button { background-color: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; border-top: #cccccc 1px solid; border-bottom: #666666 1px solid; border-left: #cccccc 1px solid; border-right: #666666 1px solid; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      .frmheader { color: #000000; background: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      .frmtext { font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 32px; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      .frmInput { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):      .intro { margin-left: -15px; }
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):            
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     </style>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     <title>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):  JsonAndroid Web Service
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131): </title></head>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):   <body>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     <div id="content">
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       <p class="heading1">JsonAndroid</p><br>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       <span>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):           <p class="intro">The following operations are supported.  For a formal definition, please review the <a href="JsonAndroid.asmx?WSDL">Service Description</a>. </p>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):           
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):           
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):               <ul>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):             
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):               <li>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):                 <a href="JsonAndroid.asmx?op=GetCity">GetCity</a>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):                 
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):                 
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):               </li>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):               <p>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):             
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):               </ul>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):             
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       </span>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     <span>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):         
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     </span>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):       
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):     
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131):   </body>
01-22 12:01:43.832: E/Response:(1131): </html>
01-22 12:01:43.882: W/System.err(1131): org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-22 12:01:43.882: W/System.err(1131):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-22 12:01:43.922: W/System.err(1131):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-22 12:01:43.922: W/System.err(1131):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-22 12:01:43.922: W/System.err(1131):     at com.example.test_project.CityData$GetCities.doInBackground(CityData.java:89)
01-22 12:01:43.922: W/System.err(1131):     at com.example.test_project.CityData$GetCities.doInBackground(CityData.java:1)
01-22 12:01:43.922: W/System.err(1131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-22 12:01:43.922: W/System.err(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-22 12:01:43.922: W/System.err(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-22 12:01:43.932: W/System.err(1131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-22 12:01:43.962: W/System.err(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-22 12:01:43.972: W/System.err(1131):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-22 12:01:43.972: W/System.err(1131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: please paste json response and stackstrace here.

Comment: where is variable result declared in doInBackground()?

Comment: check out updates post. It is declared in class.

Comment: @Jeeten Please make sure ur response json is valid json format. Use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @PrvN, your mean my code is perfect ?

Comment: @PrvN, I have just checked out your link and paste data to validate. It said Valid Json.

Comment: @Jeeten Please debug by putting a breakpoint at for loop and inside for loop and if possible please paste the json

Comment: json : [{"CityId":1,"CityName":"Vadodara"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"ahmedabad"},{"CityId":3,"CityName":"Gandhinagar"},{"CityId":4,"CityName":"Bhavnagar"}]

Comment: @HiteshJain, yes let me check.

Comment: @Jeeten your assign json array to json object. Please check array and object hierarchy.

Comment: @JeetenParmar as per you stack trace there is no json data it's return html page content and what is serviceHandler in your code?

Comment: but when i run webservice to check json data, It returned as per my above json data.

Comment: you have to put exact json value here then i can check where is error

Comment: <string>[{"CityId":1,"CityName":"Vadodara"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"ahmedabad"},{"CityId":3,"CityName":"Gandhinagar"},{"CityId":4,"CityName":"Bhavnagar"},{"CityId":7,"CityName":"Eluru"},{"CityId":8,"CityName":"Visakhapatnam"},{"CityId":9,"CityName":" Yenkapally"},{"CityId":10,"CityName":"Karimnagar"},{"CityId":11,"CityName":"Hyderabad"}]
</string>

Comment: @JeetenParmar It is XML wrapping JSON,extract this json first and assign to jsonarray in place of json object

Comment: When I paste Json data there, it is showing some errors. Can you please tell me how to assign exactly ? I am new to android so not able to understand it easily.